# What does a trailing dollar sign on a variable name mean in rxjs/Observables scope?

Tags: angular, rxjs, frontend, observable

I was looking at this document: https://rxviz.com/examples
at `pause-and-resume`

In line 10 it same something along this lines:

`pauseResume$.pipe(`

Any one knows what does that mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a convention followed by the Observable [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables) explains it in details.

This convention was added after Angular 5 (so it might happen that it couldn't be found in lower versions before 5).

This is what Angular docs said about $ sign.

**Naming conventions for observables**

> Because Angular applications are mostly written in TypeScript, you will typically know when a variable is an observable. Although the Angular framework does not enforce a naming convention for observables, you will often see observables named with a trailing “$” sign.
>
> This can be useful when scanning through code and looking for observable values. Also, if you want a property to store the most recent value from an observable, it can be convenient to simply use the same name with or without the “$”.

Answer (score 2):

It is a convention for an observable. It's not needed, but people have got into the habit of using them, like underscores for private variables.

See: https://stevenschwenke.de/DollarSignsInVariableNamesForObservablesInTypeScript

The original Angular style guide considered taking a stand on this issue, and end up not doing so. See Ward Bell's comment in the archival documentation: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2039

> We do not recommend the $ suffix. It smacks of Hungarian notation. But neither do we wish to prohibit it. A deliberate silence is our course ... for now.